# Pass inner HTML to Partial View in ASP.NET Core MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm sure this question has already been asked but don't know how to phrase it correctly. I want to do something like that:

MyView.cshtml:

```
<partial name="_MyPartial">
    <span>some content</div>
</partial>
```

_MyPartial.cshtml:

```
<div class="partial">
    @RenderInnerHtml()
</div>
```

and the result is:

```
<div class="partial">
    <span>some content</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible? If not with Partial Views, then with View Components perhaps?

Comment: Partial views and view components do not support child content. You might want to look at Razor Components instead: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/338/using-razor-components-in-a-razor-page. They support child content.

Answer (score 1):

For aspnet core razor take a look at "Templated Razor delegates" [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#templated-razor-delegates)

With those you can create razor templates using the syntax:

```
Func<T, object> template = @<div>@item.Foo</div>;
```

(where T is your type).

You can then pass that function around (in to partial views for example) and invoke as such:

```
@template(new T { Foo = "Bar" })
```

Notice that the parameter passed in is accessed via @item. (My VS adds a red squiggle for this but it can be ignored!)

If you don't want a strongly typed template, just change T to dynamic.

For your particular use case:

```
@{
    var template = @<span>some content</span>;
}

<partial name="_MyPartial" model="template" />
```

Then, inside _MyPartial:

```
@Model(null)
```

Obviously, you can introduce multiple templates and stronly typed models for the partial.